# MySQL remove duplicate records, based on custom condition

Tags: mysql, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a table "fb_products" table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fb_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `in_promo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `original_product_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  .........................................
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6254 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a search filter in my site using a SELECT, based on several conditions.

If two products have the same "original_product_id" and one of them has "in_promo" = 1 and the other - "in_promo" = 3, I need to select only the record with "in_promo" = 3. Could this be achieved using MySQL query? Here's a sample SQL, generated by the search filter in my site:

```
SELECT 
p.id,
.............
(
    SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM `gensoft_availability` WHERE code = p.code
) AS avail,
(SELECT id FROM `fb_products_products_cats_links` WHERE prod_id =p.id AND cat_id='17' AND p.visible=1 LIMIT 1) as rent_product
FROM
fb_products AS p
INNER JOIN fb_products_products_cats_links AS c ON c.prod_id = p.id AND c.cat_id IN (19,21,26,23,22,24,20,18)
LEFT JOIN fb_products_images_bg AS i ON i.item_id = p.id AND i.default_item = '1'
WHERE p.language = 'bg' AND p.archive = 0 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM fb_products
WHERE
  in_promo=3
  OR
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM fb_products f
    WHERE
      f.original_product_id=fb_products.original_product_id
      AND f.in_promo=3
  )
```

You can then add multiple conditions, or use this query as a subquery and join 
the result with other tables.

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f400e3/1).

Answer (score 1):

Add `order by promo_id DESC limit 1` to your query

Comment: LIMIT 1 mean it will select only 1 record and this isn't what I want it to do. Moreover,  I do not need ORDER BY, but a custom condition only for in_promo=1 and in_promo=3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SELECT MAX(in_promo),original_product_id FROM fb_products GROUP BY original_product_id` .

Comment: MAX(in_promo) doesn't help me. I may have three records with the same original_product_id, and if one of them is in_promo="1" and the other is in_promo="3", it shouldn't select the one with in_promo="1".

Comment: thats exactly what this statement does only the entry with in_promo=3 will be selected